Puppeteer - XLSX: Missing data in CSV from Array
I have run into an unusual issue related to CSV generation from an array of data i create through web-scraping using Puppeteer.
Through console logs in my code i can see that all the data is correctly obtained after the scrape. Thereafter, i create a CSV file mapped in a particular way with the data collected.
For some reason, not all the data is being written in the CSV file when i do a comparison with my array.
What could be the issue - code below (i have posted the part of the scrape and the code reflecting the generation of the CSV file. Can post anything relevant/required upon request
Thanks in advance
Array dummy data
// Dummy data for allProductData array
const allProductData = [
    {
        handle: '123456',
        title: 'Oak ArmChair',
        body: 'This is a comfortable oak armchair.',
        vendor: 'vendor-scrape',
        collection: 'Armchairs',
        productCategory: 'Living Room Furniture',
        type: 'Armchairs',
        tags: ['oak', 'armchair', 'living room'],
        imageSrc: ['www.example.co.uk/1', 'www.example.co.uk/2', 'www.example.co.uk/3'],
        imagePosition: '1',
        variantPrice: 99.99,
        variantSKU: '123456',
        prodURL: 'www.example.co.uk/armchair'
    },
    {
        handle: '234567',
        title: 'Walnut Coffee Table',
        body: 'This is a stylish walnut coffee table.',
        vendor: 'vendor-scrape',
        collection: 'Coffee Tables',
        productCategory: 'Living Room Furniture',
        type: 'Coffee Tables',
        tags: ['walnut', 'coffee table', 'living room'],
        imageSrc: ['www.example.co.uk/1', 'www.example.co.uk/2', 'www.example.co.uk/3'],
        imagePosition: '1',
        variantPrice: 149.99,
        variantSKU: '234567',
        prodURL: 'www.example.co.uk/coffee-table'
    },
    {
        handle: '345678',
        title: 'Leather Sofa',
        body: 'This is a luxurious leather sofa.',
        vendor: 'vendor-scrape',
        collection: 'Sofas',
        productCategory: 'Living Room Furniture',
        type: 'Sofas',
        tags: ['leather', 'sofa', 'living room'],
        imageSrc: ['www.example.co.uk/1', 'www.example.co.uk/2', 'www.example.co.uk/3'],
        imagePosition: '1',
        variantPrice: 499.99,
        variantSKU: '345678',
        prodURL: 'www.example.co.uk/leather-sofa'
    }
    // Add more objects as needed
];

The page.evaluate returns an array with objects as per below
{
                handle: handle,
                title: title + ' - ' + colour,
                body: body,
                vendor: 'vendor-scrape',
                collection: type,
                productCategory: categoryNo,
                type: type,
                tags: tagsArray.join(','),
                imageSrc: imageURLs,
                imagePosition: '1',
                variantPrice: priceText,
                variantSKU: handle,
                prodURL: prodPage
}

Below is the code related to the creation of the CSV
/// Function to create CSV data from object data
const createCSVData = (data, headers, defaults) => {
  const csvData = [];
  
  // Push headers as the first row
  csvData.push(headers);
  
  data.forEach(item => {
      const { imageSrc, ...rest } = item;
      imageSrc.forEach((imgSrc, index) => {
          const newRow = {
              'Handle': item.handle, // Copy handle only for the first image
              'Title': index === 0 ? item.title : '', // Copy title only for the first image
              'Body (HTML)': index === 0 ? item.body : '', // Copy body only for the first image
              'Vendor': index === 0 ? item.vendor : '', // Copy vendor only for the first image
              'Collection': index === 0 ? item.collection : '', // Copy collection only for the first image
              'Product Category': index === 0 ? item.productCategory : '', // Copy product category only for the first image
              'Type': index === 0 ? item.type : '', // Copy type only for the first image
              'Tags': index === 0 ? item.tags : '', // Copy tags only for the first image
              'Published': index === 0 ? defaults['Published'] : '',
              'Option1 Name': defaults['Option1 Name'],
              'Option1 Value': defaults['Option1 Value'],
              'Option2 Name': defaults['Option2 Name'],
              'Option2 Value': defaults['Option2 Value'],
              'Option3 Name': defaults['Option3 Name'],
              'Option3 Value': defaults['Option3 Value'],
              'Variant SKU': item.variantSKU,
              'Variant Grams': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Grams'] : '',
              'Variant Inventory Qty': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Inventory Qty'] : '',
              'Variant Inventory Policy': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Inventory Policy'] : '',
              'Variant Fulfillment Service': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Fulfillment Service'] : '',
              'Variant Price': index === 0 ? item.variantPrice : '', // Copy variant price only for the first image
              'Variant Compare At Price': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Compare At Price'] : '',
              'Variant Requires Shipping': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Requires Shipping'] : '',
              'Variant Taxable': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Taxable'] : '',
              'Image Src': imgSrc,
              'Image Position': index + 1, // Increment Image Position
              'Gift Card': index === 0 ? defaults['Gift Card'] : '',
              'Variant Weight Unit': index === 0 ? defaults['Variant Weight Unit'] : '',
              'Status': index === 0 ? defaults['Status'] : ''
          };
          csvData.push(Object.values(newRow));
      });
  });
  return csvData;
};

// Create CSV data
const csvData = createCSVData(allProductData, headersArray, defaultValues);

// Convert data to worksheet
const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(csvData);

console.log('All product data collected. Now generating CSV file. This may take several minutes...')

// Create workbook and add worksheet
const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'ScraperWebsite');

//Format CSV generated sheet
const dateFormatted = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
const filename = outputName+`_${dateFormatted}.csv`;
// Write workbook to file
XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename);
  console.log( 'CSV generated')


    // Read the generated CSV file
  const csvFilePath = filename; // Assuming filename contains the path to the generated CSV file
  const readCSV = fs.readFileSync(csvFilePath, 'utf8').split('\n');

  // Extract handles from the CSV data
  const csvHandles = readCSV.slice(1) // Exclude the header row
    .map(row => row.split(',')[0]); // Assuming 'Handle' is the first column

  // Find handles in allProductData that are not in the CSV file
  const missingHandles = allProductData.filter(item => !csvHandles.includes(item.handle));

  // Extract prodURLs for missing handles
  const missingUrls = missingHandles.map(item => item.prodURL);

  // Log the missing URLs
  console.log('Missing URLs in CSV:');
  console.log(missingUrls);


This is a lot of code. Can you minimize the problem a bit to isolate the exact behavior you're asking about? Without a sample of prodLinks, I can't run the code to reproduce the problem. If the issue isn't Puppeteer, but just an array and a CSV, please hardcode the resolved value of the evaluate call and remove Puppeteer from the question, again making it runnable and reproducible. See also using async await and .then together. Remove the extra .then() and flatten your code.

I have minimized the code

Thanks, but I still can't run this because allProductData is missing, so it's not yet reproducible. Ideally, that should be a simple array. Please revisit my first comment. You can probably remove the Puppeteer tag at this point since you've removed that portion of the problem. What is XLSX.utils? Is that this package? (if so, which version?)

@ggorlen I have added an example correctly formatted array of objects. However, not sure if it will replicate the issue the same way the data is retrieved through scraping

Hmm, then you'll need to re-introduce the scraping code. If the problem is in the scraping code, then all of this CSV work isn't relevant. I think you need to add debug logs to your script or single step through it to isolate exactly where the discrepancy is occurring, then if the problem still isn't obvious, update the post with the exact minimal, runnable code that isolates/reproduces the discrepancy--there's almost no way the problem is in both scraping and CSV writing--it almost certainly is one or the other (probably the scraping part, CSV writing is pretty deterministic).

In terms of the debug logs, the previous code which i removed logged the total number of objects in the array. This was compared to the number of items on the web page which always matched. The discrepancy was with the creation of the CSV file where it would not write all the data from the array - hence the question

OK, then scraping seems to be out of the picture. Regardless, we've gone back and forth for awhile now, so just let me know when you have a complete, minimal, runnable, reproducible example so I can help. Something I can simply copy-paste, run and see the problem. Until then, there's not much I can offer. BTW, I would use Papaparse rather than parsing a CSV by hand.
